# converting String to "_"

Tags: java

I'm trying to get the convert the word from a txt file to a multiple  "_" 
for example, 
let say I have to word dog I want it to print like _ _ _
so than the user can guess the letters 
I have tried this way but it didn't worked .

```
for(int i=0;i<randomWordLength;i++){
                    Integer.toString(i);
                    i=symbol;
                   System.out.println(i);
                }
```

Comment: @Andreas you should post that as an answer (I think it's *the* answer)

Comment: @Bohemian Ok, done!

Answer (score 4):

You can do it in a single line like this:

```
System.out.println(word.replaceAll(".", "_ ").trim());
```

The `trim()` is there to remove the final trailing space. If the string is just printed like that, it's not visible anyway, so you can remove the `trim()` call. It's included here for completeness.

Comment: The one problem with this is that it replaces spaces and hyphens as well, if any exist in the word.  I recommend changing it to `word.replaceAll("[A-Za-z]", "_ ").trim()` so that it will only replace letters.

Comment: @JacobG. Words with embedded non-letters are out of scope for this question, since OP was just using a "length" value. Even if you wanted to support that, that code won't do it, since e.g. `"re-do"` would become `"_ _ -_ _"`, without a space after `-`. Handling embedded non-letters requires much more complex logic, and as I said, is out of scope for this question.

Answer (score 1):

This approach works with any word.

```
String wordToGuess = "Hello";

for (int i = 0; i < wordToGuess.length(); i++) {
    System.out.print("_ ");
}
System.out.println();
```